# Kafka consumer offset export golang -- sharma or confluent-kafka-go lib

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I am trying to find a way of performing offsets reset operation on consumer group which for example in Kafka commands would be something like this:

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $kfk --dry-run --reset-offsets --topic $t --group $cg1 --to-current --export | tee topic-offset.csv
```

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $kfk --dry-run --reset-offsets --topic $t --group $cg2 --to-current
```

and then import new offset base on that export file ?

```
kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $kfk --execute --reset-offsets --topic $t --group $cg2 --from-file topic-offset.csv
```

The export import from file is not a problem ... just seems cannot find way to get and then set the offset ..

so did anyone was playing with this using `sharma` or `confluent-kafka-go` lib ?

Thanks for any suggestions in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some simple up which does the offset reset base on YMAL config

https://github.com/nXnUs25/kfk-offsets

Command line tool for LAG monitoring consumer groups listing and offset reset.

We have same offsets … Now to simulate the process we will produce messages to topic and keep consuming on one of the consumer group propertest-cg1a11 we will produce 5 messages and consume them all on that consumer group which will give us info that we consumed

`^CProcessed a total of 33 messages` 28 + 5

```
❯ ./kfkgo lag
Using config file: ~/kfk-offsets/kfk-offset.yaml
GROUP                                    TOPIC                                    PARTITION       CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               0               183             183             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               1               165             165             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               2               192             192             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               3               177             177             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               4               192             192             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               5               169             169             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               6               180             180             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               7               164             164             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               8               195             195             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               9               188             188             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               10              184             184             0
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               11              184             184             0
TOTAL LAG:                                                                                                                        0

❯ ./kfkgo lag -g propertest-cg -t propertest
Using config file: ~/kfk-offsets/kfk-offset.yaml
GROUP                                    TOPIC                                    PARTITION       CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
propertest-cg                            propertest                               0               179             183             4
propertest-cg                            propertest                               1               162             165             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               2               190             192             2
propertest-cg                            propertest                               3               174             177             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               4               187             192             5
propertest-cg                            propertest                               5               167             169             2
propertest-cg                            propertest                               6               177             180             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               7               160             164             4
propertest-cg                            propertest                               8               192             195             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               9               185             188             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               10              183             184             1
propertest-cg                            propertest                               11              184             184             0
TOTAL LAG:                                                                                                                        33
```

Now we will move the offset from propertest-cg back again to propertest-cg1a11 which will allow us to process same messages on that CG.

```
❯ ./kfkgo offset -m
Using config file: ~/kfk-offsets/kfk-offset.yaml
moving
```

and verification again :

Kafka commands: `kafka-consumer-groups.sh`

```
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      0          179             183             4               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      1          162             165             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      2          190             192             2               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      3          174             177             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      4          187             192             5               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      5          167             169             2               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      6          177             180             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      7          160             164             4               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      8          192             195             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      9          185             188             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      10         183             184             1               -               -               -
propertest-cg1a11 propertest      11         184             184             0               -               -               -


Consumer group 'propertest-cg' has no active members.
propertest-cg   propertest      0          179             183             4               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      1          162             165             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      2          190             192             2               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      3          174             177             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      4          187             192             5               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      5          167             169             2               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      6          177             180             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      7          160             164             4               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      8          192             195             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      9          185             188             3               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      10         183             184             1               -               -               -
propertest-cg   propertest      11         184             184             0               -               -               -

❯ ./kfkgo lag -g propertest-cg -t propertest
Using config file: ~/kfk-offsets/kfk-offset.yaml
GROUP                                    TOPIC                                    PARTITION       CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
propertest-cg                            propertest                               0               179             183             4
propertest-cg                            propertest                               1               162             165             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               2               190             192             2
propertest-cg                            propertest                               3               174             177             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               4               187             192             5
propertest-cg                            propertest                               5               167             169             2
propertest-cg                            propertest                               6               177             180             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               7               160             164             4
propertest-cg                            propertest                               8               192             195             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               9               185             188             3
propertest-cg                            propertest                               10              183             184             1
propertest-cg                            propertest                               11              184             184             0
TOTAL LAG:                                                                                                                        33

❯ ./kfkgo lag
Using config file: ~/kfk-offsets/kfk-offset.yaml
GROUP                                    TOPIC                                    PARTITION       CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               0               179             183             4
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               1               162             165             3
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               2               190             192             2
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               3               174             177             3
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               4               187             192             5
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               5               167             169             2
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               6               177             180             3
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               7               160             164             4
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               8               192             195             3
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               9               185             188             3
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               10              183             184             1
propertest-cg1a11                        propertest                               11              184             184             0
TOTAL LAG:                                                                                                                        33
```

more examples in README

Answer (score 1):

OK i think i found it the way just need to implement full solution but i should be good with the

```
func main() {
    brokers := []string{BK}
    kfk.Logger = log.New(os.Stdout, "", log.LstdFlags)

    cfg := kfk.NewConfig()
    cfg.ClientID = CID
    client, _ := kfk.NewClient(brokers, cfg)
    //fmt.Println(client)
    offsetMg, _ := kfk.NewOffsetManagerFromClient(CG, client)
    defer offsetMg.Close()

    consumer, _ := kfk.NewConsumerFromClient(client)
    defer consumer.Close()

    partitions, _ := consumer.Partitions(TOPIC)

    for _, p := range partitions {

        pom, _ := offsetMg.ManagePartition(TOPIC, p)
        ofs, pomStr := pom.NextOffset()
        fmt.Printf("Partition: %v -> nextOffset: %v:%s\n", p, ofs, pomStr)

    }
    fmt.Println("--")

}
```

and that gives me this output:

```
Partition: 0 -> nextOffset: 31:
Partition: 1 -> nextOffset: 30:
Partition: 2 -> nextOffset: 45:
Partition: 3 -> nextOffset: 39:
Partition: 4 -> nextOffset: 45:
Partition: 5 -> nextOffset: 39:
Partition: 6 -> nextOffset: 37:
Partition: 7 -> nextOffset: 42:
Partition: 8 -> nextOffset: 43:
Partition: 9 -> nextOffset: 35:
Partition: 10 -> nextOffset: 41:
Partition: 11 -> nextOffset: 36:
```

which is exactly same as from java command:

```
❯ kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server $kfk --dry-run --reset-offsets --topic $t --group $cg1 --to-current | sort -k3 -n

GROUP                          TOPIC                          PARTITION  NEW-OFFSET
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     0          31
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     1          30
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     2          45
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     3          39
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     4          45
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     5          39
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     6          37
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     7          42
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     8          43
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     9          35
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     10         41
propertest-cg1                 propertest                     11         36
```

so now only what left is to export this data to a file and use function

```
// ResetOffset resets to the provided offset, alongside a metadata string that
    // represents the state of the partition consumer at that point in time. Reset
    // acts as a counterpart to MarkOffset, the difference being that it allows to
    // reset an offset to an earlier or smaller value, where MarkOffset only
    // allows incrementing the offset. cf MarkOffset for more details.
    ResetOffset(topic string, partition int32, offset int64, metadata string)
```

to set new offset ...